# O que aconteceu com a tag Resharper?

Tags: suporte, tag-específica

A *tag* [resharper](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resharper) existia e continha perguntas. Eu tinha pergunta com ela. Quando respondi uma pergunta nova esta semana achei que cabia a *tag*, fui colocar e a mesma não existia. Pode ser que alguém editou o que tinha e matou a *tag*.

Tem como descobrir o que aconteceu com ela?

Comment: Aqui aparecem-me duas perguntas tuas, não sei se colocaste agora.

Comment: Eu coloquei nas 2.

Comment: Tinha alguma *pergunta* sua com ela, ou resposta? Você lembra qual?

Comment: Tinha resposta minha em pergunta com ela, mas eu acho que tinha mais coisas também. Era uma resposta ou respostas que me davam uma boa pontuação na *tag*,ela aparecia na 2a. página, ou seja, devia ter perto de 20 votos na *tag*

Comment: Olhei o que dá pra olhar como moderador e fiz também umas tentativas no Data Explorer. Não encontrei nenhum rastro da tag antiga. Só sendo admin ou dev pra descobrir, se é que é possível.

Comment: Certamente é, deve ter log de tudo. Deveria ter os logs mais acessíveis.

Comment: Você tem o link da sua pergunta antiga que tinha a tag?

Comment: @Gabe não tenho, nem lembro quantas perguntas eram, acho que era mais que uma. Só sei que eu tinha uns 15 votos (provavelmente mais) no total na tag..

Comment: @bigown Pelo log, a tag foi destruída, junto com diversas outras, dia 13/06. Ainda não sei que posts foram afetados (ou porque a tag foi destruida)

Comment: @Gabe seria bom dar uma olhada em todas estas, pode ter sido vandalismo, mesmo que velado. Eu não percebi antes porque estava meio ausente esses dias.

Answer (score 1):

Eis o que temos nos logs:

- Apenas 3 perguntas têm, ou tiveram, qualquer edição que mexia na tag [resharper](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resharper). São as 3 perguntas listadas agora na página da tag.
- No dia 13/06 o nosso sistema destruiu automaticamente a [resharper](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resharper), por não ser muito utilizada e ter apenas 1 pergunta com a tag naquele momento.

[Essa pesquisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=resharper%20-%5Bresharper%5D%20is%3Aanswer) mosta todas as respostas que citam o Resharper, mas que não tem [resharper](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resharper) na pergunta. Várias delas, inclusive as mais votadas, são suas, mas as perguntas não tem nenhuma indicação de terem sido alteradas com a remoção das tags, e elas certamente não tinham [resharper](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resharper) quando a tag foi removida no dia 13/06.

Em resumo, não há sinal algum de vandalismo ou de problema na remoção da tag (que aconteceu por causa da baixa utilização). A lista de perguntas na busca acima pode ser revista e a tag de Resharper adicionada, se for necessário.